# How to use 'so do I' in sentence?

Tags: grammar

> Sky is complete and alluring in its own self
>   But it glows more with its moon
>   So do I when I am with you

Can I use "so do I" in this quotation?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to say the same condition as "it glows more.. ", the answer is yes, you can say "so do i" in that context